# Why doesn't one tooltip work in Chrome?

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome

at [Euroworker.no](http://www.euroworker.no) we're now adding Tooltips, I've been using the [Flowplayer.org tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/index.html) to implement tooltips here. It reads the text for the tooltip from the title tag.

Ok so the problem is that on the search box, vis button, Filter Meny and Handlevogn in FF, the tooltip works perfectly.

In chrome, only the three work and Handlevogn tooltip doesn't show up, just comes up with the browser default title tooltip.

Why does this one tooltip not show up in Chrome, when the other ones do? All work fine in FF. (About to check IE and see what a mess it is.)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this at line 594: `});?`, some weird character slipped in there after the `;`, delete it :) It's throwing a JavaScript error in Chrome, also always remember to check the Console if it's available, it'll help you identify this very quickly.  For Chrome: **Right click** -> **Inspect Element** -> **Console**

It's not executing any script past this point, that's why the tooltips further down in the code aren't running, remove this illegal character and it should resolve the problem.

Comment: Y'know, I've had a million problems like this with this system. No matter how careful and meticulous I am at writing the codes, it sometimes randomly throws in illegal characters.. Thanks very much for finding that for me :)

Comment: @Nick.. I still can't get it to work.. Seems this whole site is just falling apart right now.. :( Can you offer any other advice?

Comment: @Kyle: Is there a reason you're calling `.noConflict()` everywhere? It makes the code very confusing to look at, if you don't have another library there's no reason to call it, just use `$`.

Comment: After checking in Firebug, seems that the tooltip is breaking a lot of stuff.. Apparently ".tooltip" is not a function. But I have already loaded the jQuery library in the head. I am confused.

Comment: @Kyle: You're loading `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js` multiple times, which will wipe out any plugins that were added after, you should only have jquery included once, and take out all those noConflicts, your life will be much easier :)

Comment: @Nick: thanks, I'll give that a go but Ihave to keep the noconflicts as there's prototype running on the page also. Or can I set it just once?

Comment: @Kyle: just once :) just use like `$j = jQuery.noConflict()` one time and use `$j` for the rest of the page, the loading jQuery multiple times is your tooltip problem, but this will clear things up quite a bit as well.

Comment: Taking all those out worked just great!